# Resolve Django/DRF ImageField URL from F() function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a use case where I'm attempting to override an Image URL if it exists in our database.

Here is the section of the queryset that is grabbing the `ImageField` from via an `F()` query.

```
preferred_profile_photo=Case(
            When(
                # agent not exists
                Q(agent__id__isnull=False),
                then=F("agent__profile__profile_photo"),
            ),
            default=Value(None, output_field=ImageField()),
        )
```

The Case-When is resolving correctly, but the issue is the value returns from `F("agent__profile__profile_photo")` is not the URL than can be used by the UI. Instead it is something like:
`"agentphoto/09bd7dc0-62f6-49ab-blah-6c57b23029d7/profile/1665342685--77e51d9c5asdf345364f774d0b2def48.jpeg"`

Typically, I'd retrieve the URL via `agent.profile.profile_photo.url`, but I receive the following when attempting to perform `preferred_profile_photo.url`:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'url'`.

I've tried wrapping in `Value(..., output_field=ImageField())` with no luck.

**The crux here is retrieving the url from the ImageField after resolving from F()**

For reference, I'm using `storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to implement this using some information from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992661/django-storages-get-the-full-s3-url).

Here is the helper function I used to implement:

```
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
def get_media_storage_url(file_name: str) -> str:
    """Takes the postgres stored ImageField value and converts it to
    the proper S3 backend URL. For use cases, where calling .url on the
    photo field is not feasible.

    Args:
        file_name (str): the value of the ImageField

    Returns:
        str: the full URL of the object usable by the UI
    """
    media_storage = get_storage_class()()
    return media_storage.url(name=file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't store full URL in DB. It builds absolute url on code level. Quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage):

> All that will be stored in your database is a path to the file (relative to MEDIA_ROOT).

You can use `build_absolute_uri()` method to get full URL of your files. For example you can do it on serializer level:

```
class YourSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    preferred_profile_photo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = [
            'preferred_profile_photo',
        ]

    def get_preferred_profile_photo(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.preferred_profile_photo)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer here! Given I was using `S3Boto3Strorage`, I leveraged a very similar approach with `from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class`.